# Mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket in Linux

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, xampp

i am trying to connect mysql DB with xampp in linux centos . but i am getting error like this .

```
Mysql Error : 2002- mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2).
```

i have stopped mysql server that was running separately in linux . so xampp is working properly mysql -->ok ,apache in xampp -->ok .

and i have checked phpmyadmin and previllages for root . 
you can check that http://74.205.66.7/phpmyadmin/.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your firewall? Refer to this link to enable connection to port 3306 if you are using iptables:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-18-allow-mysql-server-incoming-request.html

Comment: no , i did not checked firewall.

Comment: @WaqasRana try turning it off and check the connection to find out whether it is the cause. If so then add required firewall rules.

Comment: http://74.205.66.7/phpmyadmin/    ...check that , i am able to access phpmyadmin online . then how firewal issue?

Comment: i have added my ip in firewall , so i have to give my ip address instead of localhost in making connection to mysql. am i right?

Comment: @WaqasRana if your are connecting from localhost no need to put the ip address. Did you check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658891/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run

Comment: first of all thanks you are helping me .                                   mysql.sock file does not exist in /var/lib/mysql dir .

Comment: why that is trying to access /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ...instead of /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock